# Review-beta issues: mathjax not enabled & can't see other answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, mathjax

I appreciate the continuing hard work that the SE team is doing, and I recognize that there are some good features in the new, beta review system, but on balance I don't think it's better.  To really do a decent job of reviewing a post, I have to click the link to open the page in a new tab, which means the new system is just one additional step that gets in the way (i.e., $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C$, instead of $A \rightarrow C$).  Several issues seem to be discussed elsewhere, so I won't re-hash them here.  These are the points that I think are distinctive:

- mathjax does not seem to be enabled, so it's much harder to read and understand the posts & associated comments
- A bigger issue is that I can't really see the context of whatever I'm supposed to be judging.  In terms of keeping the site clean and useable as a long-term repository of knowledge, pages need to be seen as users would see them: *whole* with the question at the top, all other answers and all the comments displayed.  (Yes, I can click the link to open in a new tab, but why do I have to go through an intermediate page that I can't use?)  For example, if I'm supposed to judge a low quality post, I can't see the other answers that have previously been offered.  A brief answer that doesn't provide much informational context may or may not be useful for someone who comes to that page depending on what else is there, but I don't have access to that without going to the regular page.

Comment: Do you have some examples?  The only actions on low-quality answers are leave it, edit it, or delete it.  Deletion should only be used for obviously bad stuff (definitely *not* "this is a duplicate of other information" or "there's a better answer"), so if there's any possibility of it being useful just leave it.

Comment: I don't want to spend a lot of time hunting for examples. What is it you're unsure of, mathjax, or where it would've been helpful to have the context? (NB, for the latter I would say *all*, albeit only in a small number of cases will it be clearly vital.) As for the available options, styles differ I suppose; I'm reluctant to edit answers & prefer not to delete (at least at first). My standard approach is to comment based on what's going on on that page as a whole--such as the comments you suggest, which notably only make sense given the other A's, & possibly come back later to flag.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean the mathjax.  That's definitely a bug and will get fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the next build mathjax will be rendered on load of a review item.