# Review tool on already deleted answers claims "other answers: -1"

Tags: bug, review, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Review System showing deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143531/new-review-system-showing-deleted-answer)

Observe:

[image: other answers: -1]

As you can see on the right, it reads "**other answers   -1**", which is obviously wrong. There are 0 other answers. The reason for this is that the [answer was already deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556175/perfect-pdf-to-html-conversion-for-an-online-jquery-flip-book) when I was presented with the review page.

Comment: [This was also asked earlier today.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144453/179372)

Comment: @Bart, Gaffi: Not a duplicate (now) because it's about questions where there are no other answers and the one being displayed is deleted. It doesn't make sense to say there are "-1 other answers".

Comment: @Gaffi: *ping*.

Comment: @bitmask I should also have elaborated that the issues are *related*, but not *duplicated*. Basically, it seems that [a number](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144501/179372) [of issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144504/179372) [have come up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144283/179372) [over the last few days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144336/179372) [related to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143492/179372) [the new review system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144310/179372)

Comment: @Gaffi: I saw two VTC and two comments. Sorry for jumping to conclusions :)

Comment: @bitmask No worries! I'm partially to blame. ;-)

Comment: @bitmask Ah, the -1 issue is new indeed. Not sure if it's worth addressing if it's only a question to test you. But luckily that's not mine to judge. :)

Comment: @Bart: Especially if it's just to test me, saying there are -1 answers, just negates that. Besides, a bug's a bug.